# Display information

Tags: java, database, jsp

I want to display all the information got from table ...
I did this :

```
    String sql = "Select * from student";
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int id = rs.getint("idstudent");
        String name = rs.getString("studentName");
    }
    request.setAttribute("Result", rs);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("DBResult.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

I must change the ResultSet to a List to use it in , but I can't display them in a table !
how can I do it ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by you "can't display them in a table"? Clarification of the question may help me figure out what you really want. Are you trying to say you need the ResultSet data to be a List so that you can iterate over the list with .next()? I don't know if ResultSet extends the Iterable class or not.

Comment: If you're wanting to forward the results to the JSP page DBResult.jsp for display, you might want to append them to the end like so:  RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("DBResult.jsp?id=" + id + "&name=" + name);

Comment: Yes, I want the ResultSet data to be a List so I can use it in <c:foreach> tag

Comment: Well if you must use the ResultSet, cast it into a List (not sure if that would work). Otherwise I'd approach it like brano has presented.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `ResultSet` at all. Pass list of values.

Create some POJO, like `Student` with two fields: `idstudent` and `studentName`:

```
public class Student {
    private int idStudent;
    private String studentName;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Then create `List` instance. Like `students`:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

In each iterration of while loop create one `Student` object and add it to `students` list:

```
while(rs.next())
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        int id = rs.getint("idstudent");
        student.setIdStudent(id);
        String name = rs.getString("studentName");
        student.setStudentName(name);
        students.add(student);
    }
```

And finally, pass that list as an attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("students", students);
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to use Java is to write an epic shitton of classes, so you're going to want to add a `Student` class.

```
public final class Student {

    public final int id;
    public final String name;

    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    }
}
```

Then use the `ResultSet` to generate a `List` of `Student`s. `ResultSet` doesn't have any kind of `map` operator on it, so without using a nice library to wrap JDBC, you have to resort to a mutable `List` and a procedural loop to append to it.

```
    String sql = "Select * from student";
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getint("idstudent");
        String name = rs.getString("studentName");
        students.add(new Student(id, name));
    }
    request.setAttribute("students", students);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("DBResult.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Should I use this in every web application that i use Database in it ?! or there is more efficient way ?

Comment: By "efficient", do you mean less code, or more performant code?

Comment: It's probably technically possible to stream directly from the database as you're evaluating the JSP rather than loading the list into memory, but that seems rather insane. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're dealing with generating an obscenely large page.